# Example of uniformising an algebraic function

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

In my self-study of Riemann surfaces ([1]), I am stuck at seeing the connection between the uniformisation theorem and the following statement;

### Uniformisation theorem

> Every simply connected Riemann surface is conformally equivalent to just one of $\Sigma$ (Riemann sphere), $\mathbb{C}$ (Complex plane), $\mathcal{D}$ (Open unit disc).

### Statement

> The process of representing many-valued functions in terms of single-valued functions is called *uniformisation*.

The book gave the following example.

### Example

> The uniformisation of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ can be done by $x = \sin t, y = \cos t$.

I can see that as $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is a unit circle, we can represent x and y coordinates by trig-functions.

But still, it's unclear to me how the theorem relates to the above statement as well as the example above...
Can somebody help me?

### Reference

[1] G. A. JONES and D. SINGERMAN. Complex Function Theory: an Algebraic and
Geometric Viewpoint (Cambridge University Press, 1987).

Comment: You should not think of the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ as defining the init circle, since the variables here are complex numbers. Also, from the 2nd quote here, the authors of the book are quite sloppy. One iniformizes not multivalued functions but Riemann surfaces.

Comment: Is this called local uniformizing parameter?

Comment: I am not sure what 'this" refers to and which definition of a local uniformizer you are using (the terminology in the literature is inconsistent here).

Comment: I think I started seeing the intention of the authors. As a simply connected RS is a covering space (consisting of multiple branches), and this uniformising parameter $t$ can move around branches (e.g., branches are glued together for this single-valued function), the uniformisation is just a process of representing a coset of points in the covering space (under some function) by a single point in another simpler space!